# Dynamic Programming-RodCutting

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I've recently started learning algorithms.
I tried to implement the classic Rod cutting problem using a  Dynamic programming approach. I'm unable to get the correct output. Here is my code:

```
public class RodCuttingProblem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int len=5;
        int prices[]={2,5,7,3};
        rodCuttingImplementation(prices,len);
    }

    public static void rodCuttingImplementation(int prices[],int len){
        prices=reAdjustPrice(prices);
        System.out.println("");
        for(int i=0;i<prices.length;i++){
            System.out.print(prices[i]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        int dp[][]=new int[prices.length+1][len+1];
        for(int i=1;i<prices.length;++i){
            for(int j=1;j<=len;++j){
                if(i<=j){
                    dp[i][j]=Math.max(dp[i-1][j], prices[i]+dp[i][j-1]);
                }
                else{
                    dp[i][j]=dp[i-1][j];
                }
                System.out.print(dp[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Optimal Profit : "+dp[prices.length-1][len]);
    }

    static int[] reAdjustPrice(int prices[]){
        int[] newPrices=new int[prices.length+1];
        newPrices[0]=0;
        for(int i=0;i<prices.length;i++){
            newPrices[i+1]=prices[i];
        }
        return newPrices;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 4 6 8 10 
2 7 12 17 22 
2 7 14 21 28 
2 7 14 21 28  
Optimal Profit : 28
```

As per my understanding, the output should be 12.

Comment: What specifically is your question? Are you hoping that someone can debug your program for you? I would suggest that you should step through your program with a debugger and check each step to find out when it deviates from your expectations, and then use that information to correct that section of the program

Comment: Hi Kevin! Yes I did use the debugger. Just wanted to check if the method I was using is correct or not. Will try solving it on my own. Moderators, please delete this question.

Comment: You can actually delete it yourself since it is your question, though you could also post an answer yourself if you find out it is something that might be useful to someone else in the future

Answer (score 0):

I really tried to understand what your algorithm is supposed to do, but I cannot, thus I cannot find out what the problem is

some concerns:

1. reAdjustPrice is doing very weird shift, I suppose you want to indicate that length is always >= 1 and thus index in array cannot be 0, it could work, though I suggest you to think in terms of 0-based arrays
2. you have array with 4 prices, but want to split rod with length 5. Usually this is done by appending 0 at the end of array, ie initial price for length 5 is 0
3. array `dp` - it has 2 dimensions, but maximal price for every length is 1 value, so you need 1 value for each step, this is for sure one dimensional array

Here is "canonical" implementation of rod splitting algorithm:

```
static int maxPrice(final int len, final int[] prices) {
    // if len > prices.length, adjust it to have zeroes at the end
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < ((i + 1) >>> 1); j++)
            prices[i] = Math.max(prices[i], prices[j] + prices[i - j - 1]);
    return prices[len - 1];
}
```

note: this variant modifies input array, to decrease memory usage, but its very easy to modify it

Comment: Thanks Lashane! reAdjustPrice adds 0 to the length's array. 1 Meter-$2,2M-$5,3M- $7,4M-$3..so I went ahead to add '0' M-$0 just to make sense. So the price[] holds prices for different lengths from 0 meters to 4 meters. This answers your point one,two and three. And I wanted to implement a different approach(besides canonical implementation). Yet to figure out what went wrong. I must have over looked something.